# Angular2 charts (chart.js) Labels not vertical even though option is set

Tags: angular, chart.js

I am trying to display the labels on the x-axis of a barchart vertically in order to fit all labels onto the graph.  I read in another question that the way to do this is to set the max and min rotation to 90.  Even though I set the min/max rotation in options the labels still get displayed at an angle...  Any idea what i'm missing/doing wrong here?

my options code:

```
options:any = {
    scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
    scaleShowValues: true,
    scales: {
        yAxis: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }],
        xAxis: [{
            stacked: false,         
            scaleLabel: {
                labelString: 'Date'
            },
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 1,
                min: 0,
                maxRotation: 90,
                minRotation: 90,
                autoSkip: false
            }
        }]
    },
    responsive: true
};
```

Screenshot of my bar chart:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT40V.jpg

Comment: could you try to remove `scaleShowVerticalLines` and see what it does ?

Comment: @Quentin Laillé that didn't change anything...

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the chart as well please ?

Comment: @Quentin Laillé I added a link to a screenshot in the question body

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with your options, except the property names `xAxis` and `yAxis`, these are incorrect. The correct property names are `xAxes` and `yAxes`.

Also, you shouldn't be setting `scaleShowVerticalLines` and `scaleShowValues` properties. Those are deprecated.

```
options: any = {
   scales: {
      yAxes: [{
         ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true
         }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
         stacked: false,
         scaleLabel: {
            labelString: 'Date'
         },
         ticks: {
            stepSize: 1,
            min: 0,
            maxRotation: 90,
            minRotation: 90,
            autoSkip: false
         }
      }]
   },
   responsive: true
};
```